# very strange situation with a simple PHP MYSQLI QUERY

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php if (is_array($this->data)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($this->data as $key => $val): ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
Error on loading
<?php 
endif; 

global $connect;
# GET DEPOSITS

$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$get_iteme2 = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$user'");
$row = $get_iteme2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$u = $row['username'];

$get_ref = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE refferal = '$u' ");
$row_depo = $get_ref->num_rows;

$get_itemx = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ref = '$u' AND balance > '0' ");
$row_depx = $get_itemx->num_rows;
$ref_c = $row_depx * 0.01;
?>
<div id="ttt" style="margin:0 auto; width:100%;  height:40px; background:#245e76; text-align:center;  overflow:hidden; border-radius:4px; margin-top:5px;">
<div id="ttt" style="margin:0 auto; width:94%;  height:48px; background:#245e76; text-align:center;  overflow:hidden; border-radius:4px; margin-top:0px;">
<p style="font-size:12px; margin-top:10px; font-family:Arial; color:white; ">Affliate Page is now under maintenance</p> 
</div></div>  </br>  

</table>

</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my code, the strange thing is that `$row_depo` is not providing the num rows, but if I change in the query the variable `$u` to a username itself the query works, but the query is reading also the variable `$u` with the username in itself, it simply does not work if it uses the variable

Comment: Learn to use parameters.  Don't munge query strings with parameters values.

Comment: Even binding the parameters it does not work, I've tried it already

Comment: You should fix the question to have the version with the bound parameters.

Comment: I don't see you calling `$get_ref->execute()` after the `prepare()`, is this your exact code or an example of what you tried to fix it?

Comment: The reason `$row_depo` is not returning a row count is because you have not, at that point, executed the sql statement

Comment: `$get_ref = $connect->prepare(` you didn't do anything with this.

Comment: Sure, the query didn't fail for it `$get_ref = $connect->prepare(`, up until that you execute it and you're not checking for errors at all. I don't think you told us everything here. Voted to close as unclear.

Comment: Your HTML looks invalid. You have `</table>` without `<table>`. And you can't have `<div>` directly inside `<table>`, the children of a table need to be `<tr>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, or `<tfoot>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$connect->query("...")` instead `$connect->prepare("...")` and when you insert `$var` in string use `{}` or concatenate for security.

Help this help:

```
$get_ref = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE refferal = '{$u}'");
$row_depo = $get_ref->num_rows;
```

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but this line makes me think there's something else going on: *"if I change in the query the variable $u to a username itself the query works"*

Comment: prepare not return a result set

Comment: I know, that's why [I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367435/very-strange-situation-with-a-simple-php-mysqli-query#comment81687781_47367435) if this was his actual code.

Answer (score 0):

check whether this returns a value

```
 $user = $_SESSION['username'];
```

if it's returning a value then check this return a value

```
$u = $row['username'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$get_ref = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE refferal = '$u' ");
$row_depo = $get_ref->num_rows;
```

If you prepare a statement, you need to execute it before it has any results:

```
$get_ref = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE refferal = '$u' ");
$get_ref->execute();
$row_depo = $get_ref->num_rows;
```

Although, since you're not binding any parameters, you might as well just use `query()` directly, like you do in your other queries:

```
$get_ref = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE refferal = '$u' ");
$row_depo = $get_ref->num_rows;
```

Or **preferably** actually use the prepared statement with a bound parameter:

```
$get_ref = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE refferal = ?");
$get_ref->bind_param("s", $u);
$get_ref->execute();
$row_depo = $get_ref->num_rows;
```

---

Having said that, the following line in your question makes me think there's something else going on:

> if I change in the query the variable $u to a username itself the query works

This could mean that the previous query (the one where `$u` got the username from) didn't return any results:

```
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$get_iteme2 = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$user'");
$row = $get_iteme2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$u = $row['username'];
```

This is the `$u` you're using in your query. If the `$get_iteme2` query works properly but does not return any results, `$get_iteme2->fetch_array()` will return `NULL` and `$row['username']` will not exist (and PHP should give you an "undefined index" notice, but depending on your settings you might not see this).

If the query is indeed being executed properly, you'll have to debug what else is going on:

- Does `$u` contain anything, or is it empty?
- Does `$row` contain anything, or is it empty?
- Does `$_SESSION['username']` contain anything and if so, does it actually contain the **username** instead of an **email address** (You're comparing it against the `email` column instead of the `username` column, this is why naming properties is important)?

Comment: The thing is that all of them were debugged and are working properly ... but seems like it does not pass to display, since num rows display none, but it has rows ...

Comment: If you `echo` the query instead of executing it, does it contain the username you expect? And if you then execute that exact query manually, do you get results?